# Managing connections per request in Go

Tags: go, connection, mgo

Hypothetically speaking, is it good practice to connect to a database for each request and close in when the request has completed?

I'm using `mongodb` with `mgo` for the database.

In my project, I would like to connect to a certain database by getting the database name from the request header (of course, this is combined with an authentication mechanism, e.g. JWT in my app). The flow goes something like:

1. User authentication:

   ```
   POST to http://api.app.com/authenticate
   // which checks the user in a "global" database,
   // authenticates them and returns a signed JWT token
   // The token is stored in bolt.db for the authentication mechanism
   ```
2. Some RESTful operations

   ```
   POST to http://api.app.com/v1/blog/posts
   // JWT middleware for each request to /v1* is set up
   // `Client-Domain` in header is set to a database's name, e.g 'app-com'
   // so we open a connection to that database and close when
   // request finishes
   ```

So my questions are:

1. Is this feasible? - I've read about connection pools and reusing them but I haven't read much about them yet
2. Is there a better way of achieving the desired functionality?
3. How do I ensure the session is only closed when the request has completed?

The reason why I need to do this is because we have multiple vendors that have the same database collections with different entries with restricted access to their own databases.

**Update / Solution**
I ended up using `Go`'s built in `Context` by Copying a session and using it anywhere I need to do any CRUD ops

Something like:

```
func main() {
    ...
    // Configure connection and set in global var
    model.DBSession, err = mgo.DialWithInfo(mongoDBDialInfo)
    defer model.DBSession.Close()
    ...

    n := negroni.Classic()
    n.Use(negroni.HandlerFunc(Middleware))

    ...
}

func Middleware(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, next http.HandlerFunc) {

    ...
    db := NewDataStore(clientDomain)
    // db.Close() is an alias for ds.session.Close(), code for this function is not included in this post
    // Im still experimenting with this, I need to make sure the session is only closed after a request has completed, currently it does not always do so
    defer db.Close()

    ctx := req.Context()
    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, auth.DataStore, db)
    req = req.WithContext(ctx)
    ...
}

func NewDataStore(db string) *DataStore {
    store := &DataStore{
        db: DBSession.Copy().DB(db),
        session: DBSession.Copy(),
    }
    return store
}
```

And then use it in a HandlerFunc, example `/v1/system/users`:

```
func getUsers(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    db := req.Context().Value(auth.DataStore).(*model.DataStore)
    users := make([]SystemUser{}, 0)
    // db.C() is an alias for ds.db.C(), code for this function is not included in this post
    db.C("system_users").Find(nil).All(&users)
}
```

40% response time decrease over the original method I experimented with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hypothetically speaking is not a good practice because:

1. The database logic is scattered among several packages.
2. It's difficult to test
3. You can't apply DI (mainly it will be hard to maintain the code)

Replying to your questions:

1. Yes is feasible BUT you will not use the connection pool inside them go package (take a look to the code [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/head:/session.go#L195) if you want know more about Connection Pool)
2. A better way is to create a global variable that contains the database connection and close when the application is going to stop (and not close the connection every request)
3. How do I ensure the session is only closed when the request has complete<- you should checkout the answer fro your db query and then close the connection (but I don't recommend to close the connection after a request because you'll need to open again for another request and close again etc...)

Comment: In your 2nd answer you said `"create a global variable that contains the database connection"`, but this would limit me to connecting to 1 database at a time only, right? Can I do the same by creating a global slice variable containing multiple connections and close all of them when the app dies?

Comment: It depends: mainly because with dial you can connect to multiple host at time and then you can change the Mongo database by using the [DB function](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Session.DB) for changing the database. It's up to you. But, imho, it's more cleaner a separate connection per each db. By doing this you can also split each db logic

Comment: What do you mean by db logic? Every database have the same collections. Imagine you're replicating shopify or a similar service for SaaS website hosting / editor, whenever a new user registers and creates a website, we launch a new `docker` container for their "dedicated" website which has it's own `mongodb` server. We keep track of who owns each `docker` container and how to access them from our "main" `Go` server. So the difference is really only who can access which database from within the `main` `Go` server.

Comment: Not in all case same collections means same logic (maybe the query should be different). Anyway for this case you could try to create a global variable that is connected to more host, take a look [here](https://www.goinggo.net/2014/02/running-queries-concurrently-against.html), it's well explained. And then if you see that the query are slow you can always add a connections mongoldb slice

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll do some research on this and try to come up with the best solution for my app

Comment: I end up using the method I explained in the question's update. But thanks anyways